# How to disable instance recovery in ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, instance, recovery

I want my DB to stop instance recovery during opening, how to do it?

I want it because it crashes when trying to do instance recovery, I am testing some cases and want to disable it

Is there any possibility?

Comment: What is the reason your database needs instance recovery?Before proceeding any further you need to ask yourself why you wanna continue with an inconsistent database??

Comment: @steve exactly.

Comment: The reason is that 4 blocks in one datafile(that is not system datafile) is corrupted, and Oracle is trying to recover them but crashes after server tries(as I found it is caused by a bug in 10.2.0.4). I want my DB to start normally without trying recovery and I will recover that blocks myself from backup, or will move that object to another tablespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instance Recovery is necessary to get the database back to a consistent state after `shutdown abort` or some other abnormal shutdown event. Oracle is never going to let you open the database in an inconsistent state, so no, there is no possibility that you can disable it. If Oracle is crashing during Instance Recovery you need to get in touch with Oracle Support or revert to a backup.

The [concepts guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/toc.htm) has essential reading [about instances](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/startup.htm#g12154) and more particularly [what Instance Recovery is and why it is sometimes needed](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/startup.htm#CEGCHJGF):

> If an instance of an open database fails, either because of a SHUTDOWN ABORT statement or abnormal termination, then the following situations can result:
>
> - Data blocks committed by a transaction are not written to the data files and appear only in the online redo log. These changes must be reapplied to the database.
> - The data files contains changes that had not been committed when the instance failed. These changes must be rolled back to ensure transactional consistency.
>
> Instance recovery uses only online redo log files and current online data files to synchronize the data files and ensure that they are consistent.

If the Instance Recovery crash is caused by a corrupt datafile you could mount the instance, drop the offending datafile and then open the database - but you will lose the tablespace that file is in.

Answer (score 0):

> I want my DB to stop instance recovery during opening

If you shut the database down *cleanly*, then it will start up *without* Instance Recovery.
If you *don't* shut the database down cleanly, then it will start up *with* Instance Recovery.
If the database cannot do this all by itself, something's *badly* wrong.

> ... it crashes when trying to do instance recovery ...

Then something is *very* badly wrong or, more likely, you're asking it to do the wrong thing.

> I am testing some cases ...

And exactly which "cases" are you testing?

Answer (score -2):

You can perform [inconsistent OPEN](https://jdbwiki.com/doku.php?id=oracle_11g_force_open), but it is HIGHLY not recommended :)

Comment: Please include the salient point to your answer directly, lest it become useless once the link goes stale. Also it is good form to disclose your affiliation with sites you link to (if there is one).